# Gesture recognition blocks textbox in WP8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, uigesturerecognizer

I'm implementing a control with gesture interactions for Windows Universal app. But I've found an issue, that if I define gesture setting for a container than parent `TextBox` control will not be clickable after that.

Here is a simplified layout code:

```
<Page x:Class="App.MainPage">
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is a simplified code, which allows to reproduce the behavior:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private GestureRecognizer _gr = new GestureRecognizer();
    public FrameworkElement Container { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Container = this.RootGrid;
        this.Container.PointerCanceled += OnPointerCanceled;
        this.Container.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
        this.Container.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;
        this.Container.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;

        _gr.CrossSlideHorizontally = true;
        _gr.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateRailsX;
    }

    private void OnPointerCanceled(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _gr.CompleteGesture();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _gr.ProcessDownEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(null));
        this.Container.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _gr.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(null));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _gr.ProcessUpEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(null));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Debuggig said me that the main reason of this behavior is `OnPointerPressed` handler. This method is called when I click on the `RootGrid` and  `TextBox`, but doesn't when I click on the button. `object sender` is always `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid` so I cannot determine is it `TextBox` or not.

What is the most interesting that the same code work as expected for Windows app, but doesn't work for Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Could you give me any suggestion how to implement gesture recognition without affecting on controls inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a better solution than adding `PointerPressed` event handler for `TextBox` control:

```
private void TextBox_OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

It prevents calling `OnPointerPressed` for `this.Container` and allows using `TextBox` in a typical way. Not the best solution but it works as well for me.